# bash + c pipe parameter

Tags: c, bash, parameters, pipe

How can I access piped parameter in c code?

test.c

```
int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
   int i = 0;
   for (i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
      printf("argv[%d] = %s\n", i, argv[i]);
   }
}
```

Bash:

```
cat file.txt | ./test
```

It prints just first argument `argv[0] = ./test`. How can I access content of file.txt inside c code (as parameter)?

Comment: Try using `xargs`, do `man xargs`.

Comment: Thanks, but then there will be too many parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the pipe, your program gets the content of `file.txt` in its stdin. So, read from `stdin`. For example you can use `fgets()` to read line by line:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   int i = 0;

   char line[1024];
   while(fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin)) {
     printf("%s", line);
   }
}
```